# my flutter app isnt running the homepage i want it to

Tags: flutter, dart

I don't know what's happening but the app is running on my root page and not on the login page

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:loyality/Application/Pages/Login/login_page.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MaterialApp(
     debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
     title: 'Libra',
      home: LoginPage(),
    );
   }
  }
```

Comment: what do you mean ????

Comment: post the code of your `LoginPage()`